# Recommended method to retrieve data to display (from an API) in an Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

If I need to display data coming from an API in a Fragment (using an AsyncTask), let's say a list of items in a RecyclerView, I believe it shouldn't be done in onCreate() or onCreateView() since theoretically the view elements are being initialized and may not be ready to use if the call to the API is faster. Am I correct?
(I assume it's kind of impossible to get a response from an API in less time than it takes for Android to create the view though).

There is onActivityCreated() and onStart() but I am still confused about when the parent Activity calls them.
The thing I want to avoid is reloading data (making a call to the API) if it's not necessary, for instance because of an orientation change or going back to this Activity after a click on the back button from a possible "next" Activity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your first "window" (Activity or whatever) the only way I know is showing a loading text, image, etc.

If it isn't your first view you can load your data in another window and store it to later usage when the user reaches the View to show the info.

You can load it right in your `onCreate`, `onStart` or so, but as you said probably you won't have time to download the info, so again, show a `loading` page or whatever you want while your data comes.

To avoid initialization errors call your `AsyncTask` after initializing the elements. And to avoid calling the API multiple times save your data locally while the app is opened, it depends on your app requirements